# Babel not using react preset set in babelrc

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I am following a react tutorial but encountering an error whereby babel cannot understand JSX:

```
ERROR in ./components/App.js
Module parse failed: /Users/mve04/dev/react-tests/components/App.js Unexpected token (4:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| export default () => {
|     return(<h1> hello from react </h1>);
| }
| 
 @ ./client/index.js 11:11-39
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

I have installed the babel preset as follows:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react
```

and my `.babelrc` looks like this:

```
{
   "presets": ["es2015", "react" ]
}
```

My webpack config file looks like this:

```
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';

export default {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, '/client/index.js'),
    output: {path: '/',},
    module: {
    loaders: [
        {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: [
            path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
        ],
        loaders: [ 'babel-loader' ]
        }
    ],
    },
    resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js']
    },
}
```

and the app itself looks like this:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';

import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackConfig from '../webpack.config.dev'


let app = express()

app.use(webpackMiddleware(webpack(webpackConfig)));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html'));
});


app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your webpack config you specify that you only want to apply the `babel-loader` for `.js` files that are included in `./client/`, but your error message shows that `./components/App.js` is causing the problem, because it's not in `./client/` and therefore the loader won't be applied to it.

So you can either include them as well, or just exclude `node_modules`, because you will want to transpile any file of your project. Note this doesn't mean you actually transpile every possible file, but only those you actually import.

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loaders: [ 'babel-loader' ]
}
```